# "This edit changed too much"

Tags: support, suggested-edits, android-app

I came across [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/55923/ocd-micro-management-boss) on hold question and decided to edit it to keep it open. It is very badly written and therefore the edit took quite a bit of an effort to write. My suggested edit is now in the question comments.

When I was done writing, I tried to submit the edit for approval as my rep is rather low on this site. I was told my edit changes too much. I don't understand why this should refrain me from submitting this edit for approval by a moderator.

Can anyone explain to my why this message exists? I feel this should go into the moderator queue like any other edit.

Edit: I managed to edit the question at a later time, which is even weirder.

Comment: Whatever this is, it's [new to me, too.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) Screenshot?

Comment: Sounds like a new feature meant to reduce bad edits. Will try to repro too.

Comment: Well, either it's not active here on MSE based on [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/41439), or we didn't understand what you mean. Screenshot as @Emrakul suggested would greatly help

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the message but this time I get a different one. I'm on Android so it's not as easy to navigate. It last said "user cannot suggest edits to this question".

Comment: @freekvd so you're using the app? If not, mobile theme or full site theme? Those are critical details.

Comment: I was using the app. can't reproduce as another edit is currently in queue for this question.

Comment: I have come across this problem on the iOS app too. iPad mini second gen. I was editing a question to remove an irrelevant YouTube video and rearrange everything so the question actually made sense. At the time I did not have instant edit privileges.

Comment: So sounds like the API itself is doing some "sanity check" and reject such edits - only a dev can confirm for sure though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit via iOS app - "This suggested edit changes too much"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279211/edit-via-ios-app-this-suggested-edit-changes-too-much)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I don't think so; the dupe is for cases where there really isn't too much of a change (and so the check should pass), but the answer here states that the basic check is by design, and that some edits via API should fail when they would not on the site.

Comment: @NathanTuggy from what I understand, this is the same thing behind the scenes (i.e. the API), and will be fixed along with the other one. You can ask Brian in a comment just to be sure.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: This bug *will not be fixed at all, ever*, because it's by design: there's *supposed* to be a maximum change for the API. That bug *has been fixed*, because the change sensor *was too sensitive*. They are not dupes at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a mechanism to discourage spam and vandalism. A vast number of bots crawl these sites on a regular basis, submitting edits that entirely replace the content of posts with... bad things.

To combat this, edits to non-trivial posts that replace *most* or *all* of the content are rejected. This *rarely* causes problems for folks editing in good faith, but of course there are exceptions - if you encounter this, just make multiple, small, incremental edits and your changes will be accepted.

Alternately... Just log into the site before submitting your edit. This restriction *only* applies to anonymous editors - if you have an account, your edit will go into review regardless of how much of the post it changes. Given you *have* an account on The Workplace, I'm gonna guess that you somehow managed to be logged out when you first submitted the edit.

**Correction:** it appears that the API (used by the mobile apps) *always* runs the anonymous validation for suggested edits, even though it is not possible to suggest edits anonymously via the API. Will attempt to determine if this was intentional... Assuming it is (for the same reason it's run for anonymous edits via the web interface), the work-around remains the same: either submit edits piecemeal, or log into the web interface and submit them that way. **Update:** Got confirmation that this *is* by-design; API makes it too easy to cause problems otherwise. Work-arounds still apply.

Comment: So should this question here be changed to something lile "change the API to accept radical edits", or stay as bug report and (probably) be marked as [tag:status-bydesign]?

Comment: It's a support question, @shadow. Pretty sure this is intended behavior on API, but checking.

Comment: Huh, true. Thought it's a bug report, but it's just syntactic sugar. Thanks, would like to know if it's really the intended behaviour or not. :)

Comment: It appears that this is intentional, @ShadowWizard.

Comment: Thanks. So bottom line is: "don't make radical changes via the official apps, go to the website for this"?