# Cannot suggest edit to question—six-character change is “too much”

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, android-app

I attempted to suggest an edit to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/317385/32560).
After typing, I tapped Preview and got the “changed too much” error. I reduced my changes and tried again, but still got the error.

After testing, I found that changing 0–5 characters gives the “changed too little” error (as expected) and changing 6+ characters gives [the “changed too much” error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6yAl.png).

I suppose that's a bug in the validation, unless it's a Kafkaesque way of telling me I can't edit.

Comment: You can't suggest edit with less than 6 characters (status by-design), for "changed too much", read ["This edit changed too much"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267864/this-edit-changed-too-much).

Comment: Yes, I understand the intended use of both errors. The problem is that it is not possible to edit at all, because I always get one error or the other. I don't think it's intended that a six-character edit should trigger the “too much” error.

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13 Were you logged in to that site when you tried to submit the edit?

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, I was and am. I have contributed to the same site in other ways with no trouble.

Comment: Can you show us your proposed edit text with the "too much" error?

Comment: @PatrickHofman [Here](http://i.imgur.com/k4UfsJY.jpg) is a screenshot. All I've done in this example is add “> ” for the quotation and delete four spaces from the ends of lines.

Comment: That is 'too less' error. Can you show the 'too much' error?

Comment: Not a bug, see dupe. Problem is, the question is simply too short, so even 6 characters are enough to be considered a radical change. Just use a browser, and suggest your edits there. The app is **very** limited.

Comment: @AndrewT. why didn't you flag this as duplicate?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I couldn't flag it as dupe of 2 questions...

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks, fair enough.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Right you are. [*Here*](http://i.imgur.com/PsO2wh0.jpg) is the “too much” error. Same as the last example, plus I changed *them* to *they*.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You say it should work on the site, so you're confirming it's a bug in the app?

Comment: Not a bug @P1h3r1e3d13 just a limitation, same way we can't vote to delete, review, and more via the app. The app is meant more for reading and posting, everything else is a "nice to have" bonus.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Then why is there a button and an interface for submitting the edit, and why does the error say “you changed too much,” rather than “you can't edit from the app?”

Comment: You can suggest edits, but only for posts with enough characters. Don't know the exact details, but I do know that people suggest edits via the app. It's simply limited to the same restrictions as anonymous user edits.

Comment: @ShadowWizard So it's expected that that question isn't editable? In that case, the UI is obviously confusing (Kafkaesque, as I said in this question). Should I change the tags to call this a suggestion for UI improvement instead of a bug?

Comment: Sorry, you seem to not understand me and I seem to not be able to explain. Let's hope someone else will be able to.

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, I think I do understand you. But it's a bad UI that would let me spend ten minutes editing and then not let me submit that edit, while telling me a misleading reason why.

Comment: Also, the supposed duplicate says “edits to non-trivial posts that replace most or all of the content are rejected.” This edit was not nearly most of the content. Unless that's a trivial post, that description is wrong (or there is a bug).

Comment: I see. That's a very rare corner case, I don't think it's worth the development time required to fix it - unless you get this error when trying to edit other, longer, posts?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I will try to find a long post in need of a short edit and report back. Any idea what that length threshold might be?

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Okay, I suggested an edit to [this longer question](http://superuser.com/q/1063636/163315). I tried previewing after changing 4, 8, or 12 characters, and they all worked fine. (Yes, four. Three said “too little.”)

Comment: Cheers! So, guess this is settled? Or do you plan to start a new feature request anyway?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, the feature and interface are still confusing for small posts. Perhaps that should be reframed in a new suggestion. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, anyway.